# Getting the character length of a string literal

Tags: c++, string, sizeof, literals

How would you get the length (Give or take the null-terminator) of a string literal without using the cstdlib of something like this:

```
char* foo = "foobar";
cout << sizeof(foo) << endl; //Always outputs 4
cout << sizeof(*foo) << endl; //Always outputs 1
```

I have to overload the + operator on a string that may/may not include string literals in the concatenation. I have no way of allocating memory for the string without knowing the length of the char*(Or char[] I guess) being passed.

Comment: have you tried strlen?

Comment: For the last time, `sizeof` returns the size, in bytes, of a _type_ of variable. So `sizeof(foo)` is how many bytes a `char*` is, and `sizeof(*foo)` is how many bytes are in a char.

Answer (score 7):

foo is a pointer to a string. Yes, it's a constant string, but it's still a `char*` at the end of the day.

In particular, the size of a char pointer (`foo`) is 4 bytes (on a 32 bit system [well, a system with 4 byte pointers]), and the size of a char (`*foo`) is 1 byte.

There's no (standard) way of knowing the length of the string when you use a pointer to a string literal.

You can however know the size when you use an array:

```
char foo[] = "some string";
size_t len = sizeof(foo) - 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <cstring>
std::size_t length = std::strlen(foo);
```

**Edit** if you can't use any libraries, for whatever reason, then roll out your own strlen. For example

```
// simple recursion
size_t mystrlen1(const char* str)
{
  return (*str) ? 1 + mystrlen1(++str) : 0;
}
```

or

```
// iteration
size_t mystrlen_iteration(const char* str)
{
  size_t counter = 0;
  for (;*str!=0; ++str) ++counter;
  return counter; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't use any of the existing libraries to implement the solution

Comment: @TaylorBishop an interesting requirement. Can you use a computer? Anyway, I added a simple function to do that.

Comment: Recursion seems like a computationally intensive way to get to the answer. Isn't a simple while loop better? It would take less time, and in my opinion it is is easier to understand. Why did you choose a recursive algorithm instead?

Comment: @Floris it is just an example to show it can be done easily. I added an iteration example.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof(char *) is size of the pointer to the string.
you can try

```
char foo[] = "foobar";
```

sizeof(foo) = 7 (becuase it is "foobar\0" - null-terminated string)

Comment: Elegant solution. It's worth pointing out that your `foo` is an array whereas the `foo` in the question is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

May be we use a structure if we do not want standard library string.

```
struct ConstStr
{
   const size_t length;
};

struct ConstStr operator ""cstr (const char*given, size_t given_size) { return {given_size-1}; }
```

Using the string literal operator overloading we can get the size.

```
int main()
{
   auto str = "Hello world"cstr;
   cout << str.length << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the values you are getting is obvious:

`foo` is a pointer, and pointers are most often 4 bytes long. `*foo` is a char, and one byte long.  If you can't use a built in library, you can roll your own:

```
function myStrlen(char* foo) {
    int ii=0;
    while(foo[ii]!='\0') ii++;
    return ii;
}
```

I have this funny notion that most compilers record the size of a block of allocated memory by storing the value in (pointer - 1) - this is how free() knows how much memory to release. I don't know if this is universally true, and whether it's true for string constants, but I've used this successfully in the past. Yes, I'm a hacker...  In your case, I would take a careful peek at

```
*(((unsigned long int*)foo) - 1)
```

I would not be surprised if you found the string length there.

Comment: Why not to use for loop? At least your mistake will be obvious.

Comment: Slava - made edit. Answer started as a `for`; I changed my mind but didn't go back to initialize ii. Is it OK now?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str("Hello World");

    std::cout << str.length(); // 11
}
```